# NodeJS and MongoDB update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, race-condition

I have this loop in a Node and Mongo application. `console.log` will output all the 'product' names correctly, however, `rank` is usually not set correctly in the database. Interestingly enough, if I put a debug breakpoint in the program and step through slowly, it works. Any idea if there is some sort of race condition taking place, and what the best solution for making this work would be?

```
async.each(sortedProductsArray, function (product, callback) {
    console.log(product.name);
    var query = {
        productNo: product.productNo
    };

    var index = sortedProductsArray.indexOf(product)+1;
    var update = {
        // give it a rank
        $set: { 'rank': index }
    };

    // main products array
    products.update(query, update, callback);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should probably be using forEachOf and this will return the index as the second parameter, e.g.:

```
async.forEachOf(['a', 'b', 'c'], function () {console.log(arguments)});
```

`{ '0': 'a', '1': 0, '2': [Function] }`
`{ '0': 'b', '1': 1, '2': [Function] }`
`{ '0': 'c', '1': 2, '2': [Function] }`

and then you should be using this index rather than doing another search over your products collection

edit:

when you call products.update(query, update, callback); this affects the products array, and therefore may not be valid when you do your indexOf() (may not exist) which is why the rank sometimes isnt populated

Comment: I'm going to edit my question because I simplified what I have slightly and I realise it is probably a bit misleading. The array that is looped through should be a separate 'sorted' array

Comment: in any case, you should still be using forEachOf rather than indexOf - as this is a loop inside of your async loop, - indexOf can be slow on large indexes too

Comment: Ok seems to be working now, basically there was another non-async loop outside of this one (which I didn't think was important, but clearly is). That loop changed to async as well seems to have fixed it! I'm still pretty new to Node and all this sync stuff!